# Pandas: How to sum (dynamic) columns that are between two specific columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, select

I'm working with dynamic `.csvs`. So I never know what will be the column names. Example of those:

1)

```
     ETC   META    A       B       C    D    E       %
0    2.0      A  0.0  24.564   0.000  0.0  0.0  -0.00%
1    4.2      B  0.0   2.150   0.000  0.0  0.0   3.55%
2    5.0      C  0.0   0.000  15.226  0.0  0.0   6.14%
```

2)

```
  META     A      C     D    E       %
0    A  0.00   0.00  2.90  0.0  -0.00%
1    B  3.00   0.00  0.00  0.0   3.55%
2    C  0.00  21.56  0.00  0.0   6.14%
```

3)

```
   FILL   ETC   META     G      F       %
0     T   2.0      A  0.00   6.70  -0.00%
1     F   4.2      B  2.90   0.00   3.55%
2     T   5.0      C  0.00  34.53   6.14%
```

As I would like to create a new column with the SUM of all columns between `META` and `%`, I need to get all the names of each column, so I can create something like that:

```
a = df['Total'] = df['A'] + df['B'] + df['C'] + df['D'] + df['E']
```

As the columns name changes, the code below will work just for the example **1)**. So I need: 1) identify all the columns; 2) and then, sum them.

The solution has to work for the 3 examples above (1, 2 and 3). 
Note that the only certainty is the columns are between `META` and `%`, but even they are not fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select all columns without first and last by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and then `sum`:

```
df['Total'] = df.iloc[:, 1:-1].sum(axis=1)
```

Or remove `META` and `%` columns by [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) before `sum`:

```
df['Total'] = df.drop(['META','%'], axis=1).sum(axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
  META    A       B       C    D    E       %   Total
0    A  0.0  24.564   0.000  0.0  0.0  -0.00%  24.564
1    B  0.0   2.150   0.000  0.0  0.0   3.55%   2.150
2    C  0.0   0.000  15.226  0.0  0.0   6.14%  15.226
```

EDIT: You can select columns between `META` and `%`:

```
#META, % are not numeric
df['Total'] = df.loc[:, 'META':'%'].sum(axis=1)
#META is not numeric
df['Total'] = df.iloc[:, df.columns.get_loc('META'):df.columns.get_loc('%')].sum(axis=1)

#more general, META is before % column
df['Total'] = df.iloc[:, df.columns.get_loc('META')+1:df.columns.get_loc('%')].sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Did you get that this has to work for the 3 examples above?

Comment: @rafasalo - I think yes.

Comment: Sorry, after your answer I've thought about a scenario that sometimes appears and I think your answer will not work. Even the columns are not in the same position every time, please have a look again. sorry about that

Comment: @rafasalo - yes, so solution with `drop` should working (if possible `Total` or `META` are numeric), if never numeric then use `df['total'] = df.sum(axis=1)`

Comment: META is not numeric but the columns, before it, are. So your solution it's summing them.